# EntityFramwork try to load old/non existing assembly version

Tags: c#, entity-framework

since sunday i got following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Infrastructure, Version=1.0.6561.42339, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9beef0ff5a4acdf8' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Fusion Log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (10.04.2018 @ 15:56:06) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\projectsTFS\MyApp\Source\MyApp\MyApp\bin\x64\Debug\MyApp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Infrastructure, Version=1.0.6561.42339, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9beef0ff5a4acdf8
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/projectsTFS/MyApp/Source/MyApp/MyApp/bin/x64/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\projectsTFS\MyApp\Source\MyApp\MyApp\bin\x64\Debug\MyApp.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Infrastructure, Version=1.0.6561.42339, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9beef0ff5a4acdf8
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/projectsTFS/MyApp/Source/MyApp/MyApp/bin/x64/Debug/Infrastructure.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\projectsTFS\MyApp\Source\MyApp\MyApp\bin\x64\Debug\Infrastructure.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Infrastructure, Version=1.0.6674.28044, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9beef0ff5a4acdf8
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

it appears when i want to access the database via entity framework (6.2)

The first time the database is used is the code first migration:

```
//Migrator checking the current UpdateState and log the currently pending migrations
DbMigrator mig = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
foreach (var migration in mig.GetPendingMigrations())
{
    _logger.Log("Open Migration: " + migration, Category.Debug, Priority.None);
}

_logger.Log("Start Migrations", Category.Debug, Priority.None);

//Initialize the Database and Update it
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DatabaseContext, Configuration>());
// To run Seed method
mig.Update(); // X <-- ERROR
```

when I skip the code first migration the error occurs on the first select on the database.

This happens in the 'DatabaseModule' which is loaded by the main app with prism mef. All (33) project reference the Infrastructure Project (directly and NOT as dll).

What I see:

Version 6561 is from ~2017.12.18, what is also (by accident?) the date of the last migration. Version 6674 is the most recent version from today 2018.04.10. Other (Sub)namespaces, like Infrastructure.XmlSerializers or Infrastructure.resources where used from that actual version, which is shown in the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe).

The application starts without an error when I start it direclty from the Debug folder without Visual Studio.

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2017 - 15.6.5 (latest)
- .NET 4.6 - 4.7.1 (try to change this with no success)
- x64 Application
- signed Application (also try it without signing)
- 33 projects in solution
- no open/pending migrations

What i tried so far:

- cleared all bin folders
- cleared temp folders/caches (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp, C:\Windows\Temp)
- its not registered in the GAC
- Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution a lot of times
- Initialized a complete new database
- searched for "6561" in whole solution

I'm running out of ideas. Can anyone help?

looking forward to new ideas,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "Solution"

After a lot more hours of investigating and getting much deeper into the Manifests/References of my project, i used [AsmSpy](https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy) to get a more complex list of the dependencies.

```
asmspy c:\projectsTFS\MyApp\Source\MyApp\MyApp\bin\x64\Debug\ -a -s -b -i
```

and get some errors. But most errors where from system references like this:

[System Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96wff.png)

Others look more interessting, because they are referenced by Infrastructure:

[SignalR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE3EJ.png)

After this i update most of the NuGet packages.

**After that, the errors stay, but I am able to skip them and the solution starts normal!**

At least i check "Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code" and I don't see the erros anymore.